# SUM values BETWEEN specific dates in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to query a 12, 24, 36 and 48 month total for each customer

I've got a dataset that includes customer information (customer_id, products, spend, qty, purchase_date, etc) I need to display the totals for the different periods per customer

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) AS first_purchase, 
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN spend END) AS 12_mnth_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 2 YEAR THEN spend END) AS 24_mnth_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 3 YEAR THEN spend END) AS 36_mnth_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 4 YEAR THEN spend END) AS 48_mnth_total
FROM SalesTable
GROUP BY customer_id, purchase_date
ORDER BY purchase_date
```

My query shows me the following error: `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword THEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to count from the first purchase.  You cannot nest aggregation functions the way that you are doing it.  Instead, use a window function to get the minimum date for each customer and then aggregate:

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) AS first_purchase, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN min_purchase_date AND DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 12_mnth_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN min_purchase_date AND DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 24_mnth_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN min_purchase_date AND DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 3 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 36_mnth_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN min_purchase_date AND DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 4 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 48_mnth_total,
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             MIN(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) as min_purchase_date
      FROM SalesTable s
     ) t
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY first_purchase;
```

You ca simplify the logic by removing the first comparison in the `case`:

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) AS first_purchase, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date <= DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 12_mnth_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date <= DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 24_mnth_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date <= DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 3 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 36_mnth_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date <= DATETIME_ADD(min_purchase_date, INTERVAL 4 YEAR) THEN spend
           END) AS 48_mnth_total,
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             MIN(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) as min_purchase_date
      FROM SalesTable s
     ) t
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY first_purchase;
```

Any purchase is logically on or after the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The function DATETIME_ADD is not closed. I put it here INTERVAL 1 YEAR")".

Wouldnt know the exact sintax but its a good guess.

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) AS first_purchase, 
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN spend END) AS 12_mnth_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) THEN spend END) AS 24_mnth_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 3 YEAR) THEN spend END) AS 36_mnth_total,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_date BETWEEN MIN(purchase_date) AND DATETIME_ADD(MIN(purchase_date), INTERVAL 4 YEAR) THEN spend END) AS 48_mnth_total
FROM SalesTable
GROUP BY customer_id, purchase_date
ORDER BY purchase_date
```